# Does stacking multiple linear layer have some documented improvements?

Tags: neural-networks, references, linear

I know that theoretically stacking multiple linear layer does not make any sense, as multiple affine transformations are no more powerful than a single one, however I heard many DL practitioner saying that multiple linear layer speed up the learning of a network

However, I found no documented case of this in the literature or in any paper on arxiv that I was able to find being related to this... any insight/reference?

Some paper that references this behavior:

- [arxiv.org/pdf/1912.02975.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.02975.pdf): *To show that overparametrization alone is an important implicit regularizer in RL, LQR allows the use of linear policies (and consequently also allows stacking linear layers) without requiring a stochastic output such as discrete Gumbel-softmax or for the continuous case, a parametrized Gaussian. This is setting able to show that overparametrization alone can affect gradient dynamics, and is not a consequence of extra representation power due to additional non-linearities in the policy*
- [arxiv.org/pdf/1811.10495.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.10495.pdf) *we expand each linear layer in a given compact network into a succession of multiple linear layers. Our experiments evidence that training such expanded networks, which can then be contracted back algebraically, yields better results than training the original compact networks, thus empirically confirming the benefits of over-parameterization.*

however none of those paper even tries to argue why this happens, they just limit themself to observe this behavior

Comment: You write "I heard many DL practitioner saying that multiple linear layer speed up the learning of a network" -- can you provide some examples & citations to these claims? This will help people research and find the references that you seek.

Comment: @Sycorax the last time i heard this is from this video claimed by this researcher/professor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAkGYR0ykX4&ab_channel=Multi-AgentSystemsatAlanTuringInstitute which is pretty known in the RL research area (minute 27:22)

Comment: From experience, I can say that it's unlikely that anyone will watch almost 30 minutes of a YouTube video to answer a question. Perhaps you could [edit] to include written resources that make this claim?

Comment: This seems like helpful material to include in an [edit].

Comment: @Sycorax done...

Comment: The literature review in "ExpandNets: Linear Over-parameterization
to Train Compact Convolutional Networks" seems like a good place to start. By my count, the authors cite 12 papers about this phenomenon in the first page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some papers giving theoretical guarantees for Multiple Linear Layer Networks (more generally known in the literature as Deep Linear Networks) which should be of interest to you :

- First, the paper [Deep Linear Networks with Arbitrary Loss: All Local Minima Are Global](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/laurent18a/laurent18a.pdf) shows that, under some technical assumptions, all local minima of Deep Linear Networks are in fact global. This is good news as it guarantees that Deep Linear Networks trained with SGD will generalize "almost" as well as the [Empirical Risk Minimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization) (where "almost" corresponds to the how close your SGD output is to the minimizer)
- As for actual speed-up of the training, you can have a look at these : [Exact natural gradient in deep linear networks and its application to the nonlinear case](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2018/hash/7f018eb7b301a66658931cb8a93fd6e8-Abstract.html), [Global Convergence of Gradient Descent for Deep Linear Residual Networks](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/hash/14da15db887a4b50efe5c1bc66537089-Abstract.html), [Exponential Convergence Time of Gradient Descent for One-Dimensional Deep Linear Neural Networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v99/shamir19a.html) and [A Convergence Analysis of Gradient Descent for Deep Linear Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02281). They are all quite technical, but from my understanding, the main takeaway message from all of these is that, when properly initialized, (stochastic) gradient descent on Deep Linear Networks converges extremely (read : exponentially) fast towards the global minimum, and the speed of convergence seemingly increases with the number of linear layers you add. This behavior is specific to Deep Linear Networks and does in general not hold for Non-Linear networks.

In conclusion, yes, stacking linear layers is beneficial for **training** purposes : if you add more linear layers, the above papers indicate that SGD should converge to the global minimum quicker, and hence generalize almost as well as the global minimizer.
However, as you correctly point out, the **representation power of deep linear models is very limited** (basically the same as a regular linear model), so these models remain of little practical relevance for solving complex regression tasks, and the main interests of the above papers is that they provide some theoretical tools which help us build a theory towards a better understanding of Deep (Non-Linear) Networks.

As a quick last note, I just want to point out that Deep Linear Models are far from being completely useless : they are for instance at the core of [Deep Matrix Factorization Models](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/2017/0447.pdf), which have numerous applications.

Comment: thank you so much for the very clear answer, appreciated